# How to remove last element from checkbox

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I want to remove the last checkbox option from this loop.

```
- StandardSize.all.each do |s|
   = f.check_box :standard_sizes_id_in, {multiple: true}, s.id, nil
   = s.name
```

This is how I get the checkbox option, when I did inspect element.
From here I want to remove 'custom size' option (which is the last checkbox name). How to do so?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_1">S
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_2">M
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_3">L
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_4">XL
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_5">XXL
<input type="checkbox" value="10" name="q[standard_sizes_id_in][]" id="q_standard_sizes_id_in_10">Custom Size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
- StandardSize.all[0..-2].each do |s|
   = f.check_box :standard_sizes_id_in, {multiple: true}, s.id, nil
   = s.name
```

Because `StandardSize.all` just return an array so you can apply any methods on array to filter it. For more information: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html

Comment: How to write condition to delete when 'standard_size = Custom size'

Comment: @sree Could you please more specific about your StandardSize's data? If "Custom Size" is the last item in `StandardSize.all` then the solution above did solve your problem, didn't it?

Comment: i want to check custom size option is there in this list. if there then delete it.

Comment: the above condition deletes last element,its fine.but if custom size option is not added in standard size table, then it deletes the size which is the last one which is not custom size. so i need to avoid it

Comment: @sree In that case, it will be `- StandardSize.all.reject { |item| item.name == 'Custom Size' }.each do |s|`

Comment: @sree you're welcome. please give this answer one up vote so every have same problem with you can find it easier :)